# How would I hide the headers in an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm recentrly trying to learn about APIs using jquery and ajax. When setting the header of ajax, I write something like this:

```
headers: {
    "My-First-Header":"first value",
    "My-Second-Header":"second value"
},
```

I'm in a simple school project and I want to hide the headers informations so no one can see it just looking my sources files. How can I do it?

Comment: You can obfuscate it but you can't really hide it.

Comment: @ハセン do you have any example for this?

Comment: Not off the top of my head but try googling for "javascript obfuscator"

Comment: Beaware that if you obfuscate code handed in to a school assignment it might well earn you minus points. Personally if I was grading a programming assignment and the student purposely obfuscated his code I would probably fail him.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible..., if your javascript is server-side (e.g. node.js) that would be a yes. Anyway you can just minify your javascripts with some takrunner eg. gulp.